# How does UIAppearance's Appearance Proxy work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

I'm trying to understand the details of [`UIAppearance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Both of the methods of the `UIAppearance` protocol return an "appearance proxy" of type `id`. What is this "appearance proxy"? Is it similar to the File's Owner proxy, an object that will be filled in at a later date? How does it change the appearance of onscreen objects?

Comment: Did you find answers to your questions? I am interested in as well.